# Warning issue when installing Hadoop 2.8.2 on Mac OS

Tags: hadoop

I am attempting to install Hadoop 2.8.2 with Java 8 on Mac OS, but i ran into this error after typing the hstart command in terminal. (I initially had Java 9 installed, but switched to Java 8 becuase i thought that Java 9 was causing the issue, but the warning still remains.

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
>   Illegal reflective access by
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
>   (file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.8.2.jar)
>   to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance() WARNING: Please
>   consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil WARNING:
>   Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal
>   reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations
>   will be denied in a future release 18/02/04 23:38:54 WARN
>   util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
>   platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable Starting
>   namenodes on [localhost] localhost: namenode running as process 34039.
>   Stop it first. localhost: datanode running as process 34125. Stop it
>   first. Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0] The authenticity of host
>   '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.

This is in my `"/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2/libexec/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh"` file:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
```

Comment: Remove the `java.security.krb5` properties... Why do you need them?

Comment: @cricket_007 hey, oh it was actually 2.8.2  (copy and paste error...) I have removed the java.security.krb5 properties, but the same error still occurs

Comment: Okay, well, it appears that you already have Hadoop running... `namenode running as process 34039. Stop it first. `